# SQL Query to Group Records and Ensure All Records In Each Group Are Present in Another Query Result

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two SQL queries that I'm trying to combine effectively to achieve a specific result. I have a table called "orders" with a query that dynamically generates a list of "person_id" values that have exactly one order:

```
SELECT
    person_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(order_id) = 1
```

This query outputs a list of "person_id" values, such as (001, 002, 003, 004, 006, 008, 009).

I also have another table as follows:

| ID | person_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 |
| 1 | 002 |
| 1 | 003 |
| 1 | 004 |
| 2 | 005 |
| 2 | 006 |
| 2 | 007 |
| 3 | 008 |
| 3 | 009 |

Now, I want to write an SQL query that groups the records by "ID" and ensures that all the "person_id" values within each group are present in the result of the first query. In this case, the desired output would be ID 1 and 3 because all the "person_id" values in these groups (001, 002, 003, 004 for ID 1, and 008, 009 for ID 3) are in the first query's result. ID 2 is not because two (005 and 007) of its records are not in the first query's result.

Can anyone help me construct an SQL query to achieve this result? Thank you!

I have been trying but couldn't get it to work, I'm not sure if there is a more direct way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using, and show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be with EXCEPT (for SQL Server) or MINUS (for some other database servers):

```
with orders as (
select * 
from  (values
('001'), ('002'), ('003'), ('004'), ('006'), ('008'), ('009')) T( person_id)
), AnotherTab as (
select *
from (values
 (1 ,'001'),(1  ,'002'),(1  ,'003'),(1  ,'004'),(2  ,'005')
,(2 ,'006'),(2  ,'007'),(3  ,'008'),(3  ,'009')
) T(ID, person_id)
)
select distinct atab.id
from AnotherTab atab
where not exists (select atab2.person_id
                  from AnotherTab atab2
                  where atab2.Id=atab.id
                  except
                  select o.person_id
                  from orders o
                  )
```

Comment: `EXCEPT` is also ANSI/ISO SQL.